# Supply 5v to peripheral using solder pads and not GPIO?

Tags: gpio, power-supply, screen, alternative-power, hat

This seems like a simple enough question but it hasn't been easy to find an answer!

I have a Pi3 (with recommended PSU), official screen, official camera and I've now added the respeaker 2-mics Pi Hat:
https://www.seeedstudio.com/ReSpeaker-2-Mics-Pi-HAT-p-2874.html

Originally I powered the screen from the GPIO as per the instructions: micro USB into Pi and GPIO 5v +- into screen. I've now got the Respeaker Pi Hat which requires the use of all the GPIO pins and forces me to use a 2nd micro USB supply just for the screen!

The question is, would it possible to tap into the 2 solder pads on the underside of the Pi where the micro USB is situated and send power to the screen from here? Ideally I would like to avoid soldering straight onto the pi but rather that than the use of two power supplies. Unless there is another solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soldering to the Pi board is not recommended; for a start the solder is low lead, and has a high melting point.

If you are going to try, don't even attempt the solder pads - there are test points with the supply voltage.

It would be better to solder to the pins on the HAT; even better use proper external connections.